# spring lemon - "Request method 'GET' not supported" on email verification

Tags: spring-lemon

I am trying to use spring lemon for user handling. I am sending a registration request which gets a 201 response and sends an email to the user, but when the user clicks the link he gets a "Request method 'GET' not supported" response. I looked at the spring lemon code, and in LemonController.java line 104 the verifyUser method uses a @PostMapping annotation. Shouldn't it use a GET annotation? The link from the email creates a GET request, not POST.

Thanks.

Comment: It's clear that you're trying to make a GET request on a POST method. You simply cannot do that. You have to be more specific and provide some code so we can check it out.

Comment: I can't provide an isolated example. Just consider this - the user gets a verify link via email. As far as I know clicking this link always generates a GET request, not POST.

Comment: Well in that case either your mapping is wrong or generated url for clicking is incorrect.

Comment: I didn't generate the mapping. I am using a library called spring lemon and this is where I think the wrong url mapping is.
This is the method I spoke about (line 104)
https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon/blob/master/src/main/java/com/naturalprogrammer/spring/lemon/LemonController.java

and this is the method which sends the email to the user (line 246)
https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon/blob/master/src/main/java/com/naturalprogrammer/spring/lemon/LemonService.java

Seems to me pretty clear that it sends a url for GET and expects a POST.

Comment: OK, I understand my mistake. I am supposed to implement the verification page myself and send a POST request to the API url.

Comment: Yeah that is what you need.

Comment: Correct - see https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/lemon-demo-angular1 for an example front-end